# Can't get OC1B (pin 10) to output

Tags: arduino-uno, led, atmega328, timers, port-mapping

I'm trying to get this program to use channel B for the output waveform using the phase correct PWM mode and using OCR1A as the top. With a 50% duty ratio I'm attempting to  get a 10 Hz freq. I'm able to adjust the OC1A (Pin 9) if I set TCCR1A to 0x43; but nothing comes from pin 10. Code:

```
include "avr/io.h"

void setup()  
{  
 DDRB = 0x6; //set pins 9 and 10 as output  

 /*set operation Toggle mode; WGM13:0 = 1011 phase correct PWM  
CS12:0 = 101 prescaler = 1024*/
 TCCR1A = 0x23;  
 TCCR1B = 0x15;

 OCR1A = 0x187; //391 for 50% duty cycle  
 TCNT1 = 0; //clear counter and update OCR1A  
}  
void loop()  
{ }
```

Comment: It's much more readable to configure registers using bit operations like `TCCR1A |= (1<<COM1A1);`. Pin 10 refers to the arduino's pin 10?

Comment: Haven't looked into the spec but maybe you want to try setting `OCR1AL = 0x87` and `OCR1AH = 0x01` separately.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Timer/Counter 1 in Fast PWM Mode with TOP set to OCR1A:
`OCR1A`only describes the number to what it counts up so, 0…391 in your case.
You have to define the duty cycle with `OCR1B`. 50% would be 195.